# How can I display an image in the middle of a table, not in the top?

Tags: html, email, html-email

It's about this module, I need to display the image in the middle, not in the top

```html
<!-- D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
<table align="center" bgcolor="#E4F4F4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E4F4F4 !important;" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td class="padding-lr_20">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="600">

                    <tr valign="bottom">
                      <td align="center">
                        <!--LEFT-->
                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="300">

                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" width="100%">
                              <a alias="Body-Image" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="[link goes here]" style="color: #000000; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;"><img alt="[add alt text here]" class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100" style="display: block;width:100%" width="300"> </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--//LEFT-->
                        <!--[if gte mso]>
                  </td>
                 <td valign="top">
                   <![endif]-->
                        <!--RIGHT-->
                        <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="300">

                          <tr valign="middle">
                            <td align="center" class="padding-tp_20 padding-lr_0" style="padding: 0 32px;" width="265">
                              <!--[if mso]>
                    <div style="padding-top:20px;"></div>
                    <![endif]-->
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" class="h1 text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 26px;line-height: 30px;color: #000000;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: -.02em; text-align:left;">
                                    Text Text Text Text Text Text </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" class="body_text text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 22px;color: #000000;font-weight: 400; text-align:left;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--//RIGHT-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #ffffff !important;" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 40px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- //D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
```

I need to center vertically the image. I was trying adding valign="middle" on the TR tags, but it didn't work.

Comment: The awful thing about styling HTML emails is that there are a large number of commonly used email clients and all of them have different issues, so what might be the solution that works in one client (e.g. gmail.com) might break the layout in another (e.g. Apple Mail or Outlook Mobile.) That makes this question very hard to answer. I would save yourself the headache and just use https://get.foundation/emails.html plus some email rendering QA service to test against your target audience clients. Developing for emails is stuck in IE6 territory unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you need with the image its just a small fix.

```
    <!-- ... [earlier code] ... -->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> <!-- valign="middle" added here -->
      <!--LEFT-->
      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="300">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%"> <!-- valign="middle" added here -->
            <a alias="Body-Image" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="[link goes here]" style="color: #000000; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;">
              <img alt="[add alt text here]" class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100" style="display: block;width:100%" width="300"> 
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--//LEFT-->
      <!-- [rest of your code] ... -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- ... [later code] ... -->
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, I added the code, but it still didn't work, even in an HTML editor. Anyway, thank you for the link, it is a great resource!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center the image vertically, you can use CSS Flexbox

```
<!-- D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
<table align="center" bgcolor="#E4F4F4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E4F4F4 !important;" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td class="padding-lr_20">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="600">
                    <tr valign="bottom">
                      <td align="center" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                        <!--LEFT-->
                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="300">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" width="100%">
                              <a alias="Body-Image" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="[link goes here]" style="color: #000000; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;">
                                <img alt="[add alt text here]" class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100" style="display: block;width:100%" width="300">
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--//LEFT-->
                        <!--[if gte mso]>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <!--RIGHT-->
                        <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="300">
                          <tr valign="middle">
                            <td align="center" class="padding-tp_20 padding-lr_0" style="padding: 0 32px;" width="265">
                              <!--[if mso]>
                              <div style="padding-top:20px;"></div>
                              <![endif]-->
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" class="h1 text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 26px;line-height: 30px;color: #000000;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: -.02em; text-align:left;">
                                    Text Text Text Text Text Text
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" class="body_text text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 22px;color: #000000;font-weight: 400; text-align:left;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--//RIGHT-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #ffffff !important;" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 40px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- //D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
```

what i added to your code is `style="display: flex; align-items: center;"` to `td`.

Comment: The context is html email, so this will not work reliably https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-align-items/

Answer (score 0):

To get what you're after, using your HTML, you'll need to set `valign="middle"` (as andrewbyteforge pointed out) *and* `height="300"` to the `<td>` that contains your image. Your original HTML has `<td align="center" width="100%">`, but it needs to be `<td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" height="300">`. I hope this helps.

```html
<!-- D2 - BANNER - LIRT --><table align="center" bgcolor="#E4F4F4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E4F4F4 !important;" width="600">
 
  <tr>
   <td class="padding-lr_20">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="600">
     
      <tr>
       <td align="center">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         
          <tr>
           <td align="center">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="600">
             
              <tr valign="bottom">
               <td align="center">
                <!--LEFT--><table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="300">
                 
                  <tr>
                   <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" height="300">
                    <a alias="Body-Image" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="[link goes here]" style="color: #000000; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;"><img alt="[add alt text here]" class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100" style="display: block;width:100%" width="300"> </a></td></tr></table><!--//LEFT--><!--[if gte mso]>
                  </td>
                 <td valign="top">
                   <![endif]--><!--RIGHT--><table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="300">
                 
                  <tr valign="middle">
                   <td align="center" class="padding-tp_20 padding-lr_0" style="padding: 0 32px;" width="265">
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <div style="padding-top:20px;"></div>
                    <![endif]--><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                     
                      <tr>
                       <td align="center" class="h1 text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 26px;line-height: 30px;color: #000000;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: -.02em; text-align:left;">
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text </td></tr><tr>
                       <td align="center" class="body_text text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 22px;color: #000000;font-weight: 400; text-align:left;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </td></tr></table></td></tr></table><!--//RIGHT--></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #ffffff !important;" width="600">
 
  <tr>
   <td style="padding-top: 40px;">
   </td></tr></table><!-- //D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
```

Without setting the height there is no "middle" it's all collapsed based on its content, the image in this case, and it just sits at the top of its parent `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, as far as the content goes was put the image and the text in separate cells in the same row. I think this is also what andrewbyteforge meant by his "simple fix"

There's a lot of code in there that I think is redundant, but I left it as is since I'm unsure what css styling various elements and classes have.

From what I can tell, `valign="middle"` was having trouble centering the contents of the cell because there were 2 table elements within the content. After I separated them into separate side-by-side cells and added `valign="middle"` to the containing cells it seemed to work.

## Working Code

```html
<!-- D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
<table align="center" bgcolor="#E4F4F4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E4F4F4 !important;" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td class="padding-lr_20">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="600">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                                    <!--LEFT-->
                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="300">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" width="100%">
                                                <a alias="Body-Image" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="[link goes here]" style="color: #000000; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;"><img alt="[add alt text here]" class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100" style="display: block;width:100%" width="300"> </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--//LEFT-->
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                                    <!--RIGHT-->
                                    <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container h-auto" height="300" width="300">
                                        <tr valign="middle">
                                            <td align="center" class="padding-tp_20 padding-lr_0" style="padding: 0 32px;" width="265">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <div style="padding-top:20px;"></div>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" class="h1 text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 26px;line-height: 30px;color: #000000;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: -.02em; text-align:left;">
                                                            Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" class="body_text text-center" style="font-family:  sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 22px;color: #000000;font-weight: 400; text-align:left;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                                            Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--//RIGHT-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" role="presentation" style="background-color: #ffffff !important;" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top: 40px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- //D2 - BANNER - LIRT -->
```